# virt manager does not let me remove Display spice

Tags: windows, graphics-card, fedora, gpu, qemu

I try removing spice in Qemu virt-manager and I keep getting

```
Error Removing Device: unsupported configuration: Spice audio is not supported without spice graphics

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/delete.py", line 338, in remove_devobj_internal
    vm.remove_device(devobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 641, in remove_device
    self._redefine_xmlobj(xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 391, in _redefine_xmlobj
    self._redefine_xml_internal(origxml, newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 374, in _redefine_xml_internal
    self._define(newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1137, in _define
    self.conn.define_domain(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 554, in define_domain
    return self._backend.defineXML(xml)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4495, in defineXML
    if ret is None:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Spice audio is not supported without spice graphics
```

even thow I am now not using spice graphics. After all my test I can't seem to not be able to uses anything in my display tab except for spice.
example config:

```
<graphics type="spice">
  <listen type="none"/>
  <image compression="off"/>
</graphics>
```

If you know that is wrong I would love to know because it has been this way for weeks while trying to do a single GPU Passthrough.
Here is my some guides I followed and I'm on fedora(37) with nvidia

https://github.com/mike11207/single-gpu-passthrough-amd-gpu

https://github.com/joeknock90/Single-GPU-Passthrough

https://github.com/ilayna/Single-GPU-passthrough-amd-nvidia

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTWf5D092VY
Thanks in advance for all the help.

UPDATE: I tried installing with VNC INSTEAD of spice and it just loaded forever.